# Best way to do multiple choice in Unity 2D?

Tags: unity, c#, game-mechanics

So I'm about to start development on a game in unity that is going to require multiple choice each choice having a some what unique function. I've thought of 2 ways of doing this but I'm unsure if there is an easier way as I've never really worked with unity.

So the first way I was thinking about doing this and I think better then the second would be to make a class for each choice with all the functions that belong to that choice in there and then just calling it when its needed. However, I don't know if this will scale very well as I will have over 100 different events with their own choices...

The second way I was thinking was to do it via JSON and then just code each function to parse that. So for example: `addmoney`, `dothis`, `dothat` etc... However this seems like a lot more work then it would be worth so I'm not 100% sure...

So I'm wondering what option would be better and if anyone else has any suggestions I'd love to hear!

Answer (score 0):

Have a base abstract class of Choice.  It has options such as "Choose".  Then the functionality of choose is implemented in the subclasses.

```
public abstract class Choice
{
    void Choose();
}

public class RightChoice : Choice
{
    public void Choose()
    {
        Debug.Log("You made the right choice!");
    }
}

public class LeftChoice : Choice
{
    public void Choose()
    {
        Debug.Log("You made the left choice!");
    }
}
```

Then you can proceed to sub-class LeftChoice and RightChoice as needed.

*Disclaimer:  For the sample code above, an interface would be better.  But I suspect that an abstract class will be better for your situation.*

Answer (score 0):

you have lots of choices. i list a few and you can choose which works best for you.

1) simple **if.. else** statement. its hard-coded and you dont have much freedom

2) switch case statement. its not OO and is not adviced.

3) using **command** pattern. this is like @Evorlor done in his answer. you can change command or choices by simply changing the class.

4) using **delegate** and events. you can simply Make a Delegate like **Action** and change choices just by set different function to it.